# Me genera error al compilar la concatenacion

Tags: java-8

```
private String concat(String[] arr) {

    String cad = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            cad += ", ";
        }
        cad += arr[i];
    }
    return cad;

}
```

y me sale un error al compilar

Answer (score 0):

El método concat tendrá que ser static, he hecho pruebas y es el único error que me sale, las pruebas han sido las siguientes (Y el método funciona correctamente):
Por una parte tengo un array que relleno en la misma linea:

```
String [] arr = {"Elemento1", "Elemento2", "Elemento3"};
```

Por otra parte creo una variable donde guardaré el resultado del método y lo imprimo por consola:

```
String result = concat(arr);
System.out.println(result);
```

Y por otra parte está tu método pero con el único cambio es que lo he puesto como static, cabe decir que esto todo lo he puesto en la clase main.

```
private static String concat(String[] arr) {
    String cad = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if (i > 0) {
          cad += ", ";
        }
        cad += arr[i];
    }
    return cad;
}
```

Aquí está la clase completa donde hice las pruebas por si quieres comprobar que de verdad funciona:

```
public class Concat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] arr = {"Elemento1", "Elemento2", "Elemento3"};
        String result = concat(arr);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    private static String concat(String[] arr) {
        String cad = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                cad += ", ";
            }
            cad += arr[i];
        }
        return cad;
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: me sirvio gracias

Comment: @walteryesidlondoñoescudero podrías ponerla como solucionada, así me ayudas a mi y a otras personas que busquen la misma duda.